# Get value in a HTML tag with JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

this is the XML that I'm trying to parse...

```
<BOLETIN>
<localidad>Palencia</localidad>
<predicciones_timestamp>07-10-2011 00h</predicciones_timestamp>
<altitud>797</altitud>
    <fecha>2011-10-07
        <titulo1>Día</titulo1>
        <cielo1>Cubierto</cielo1>

        <titulo2>Noche</titulo2>
        <cielo2>N-Cubierto</cielo2>
        ....
    </fecha>
```

And this is the JQuery function that I'm using...

```
$(xml).find('BOLETIN').each(function(){
    var localidad = $(this).find('localidad').text();
    $( "#localidad" ).append( localidad );                      
    $(this).find('fecha').each(function(){
        var titulo1 = $(this).find('titulo1').text();
        var cielo1 = $(this).find('cielo1').text();
```

Using something like:

```
var fech = $(this).find('fecha');
```

is not working. It is taking fecha as an Object of type Object. If I try:

```
var fech = $(this).find('fecha').text();
```

The value of fech is empty.

How can I get the value 2011-10-07 from the XML??

Thanks a lot,
VM

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the [parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) method in JQuery - its a lot easier to find / update information within XML than using `find()` or `each()`

Comment: Thanks ManseUK but I couldn't really find a way to solve this problem on the JQuery web.

Comment: @VictorMartínezGrandmontagne Your XML is not valid XML - so that parsing of the XML using the standard parsing routines in JQuery are not going to work - you will need to extract the string - probably using the substring method in javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
 <BOLETIN>
<localidad>Palencia</localidad>
<predicciones_timestamp>07-10-2011 00h</predicciones_timestamp>
<altitud>797</altitud>
    <fecha date='2011-10-07'>
        <titulo1>Día</titulo1>
        <cielo1>Cubierto</cielo1>

        <titulo2>Noche</titulo2>
        <cielo2>N-Cubierto</cielo2>
        ....
    </fecha>



 $(xml).find('BOLETIN').each(function(){
 var localidad = $(this).find('localidad').text();
 $( "#localidad" ).append( localidad );                      
 $(this).find('fecha').each(function(){
  var date  = $(this).attr('date');
  var titulo1 = $(this).find('titulo1').text();
  var cielo1 = $(this).find('cielo1').text();
```

i guess this should work

if you can't edit the xml here's another solution :

```
$("fecha")
        .clone()    //clone the element
        .children() //select all the children
        .remove()   //remove all the children
        .end()  //again go back to selected element
        .text();    //get the text of element
```

Comment: Thanks FrozenFlame but I can't change the XML, it is coming from a web.

Comment: check the new solution i found  . hope it helps